# How to get a table row click event to work using Aurelia that then navigates to another page

Tags: aurelia

I want to create a Master/Detail page with table being the master that you click on a row and then it navigates to a detail page

Take the Aurelia ContactManager example and replace the list with a table

List example:

```
<li repeat.for="contact of contacts" class="list-group-item ${contact.id === $parent.selectedId ? 'active' : ''}">
        <a route-href="route: contacts; params.bind: {id:contact.id}" click.delegate="$parent.select(contact)">
          <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">${contact.firstName} ${contact.lastName}</h4>
          <p class="list-group-item-text">${contact.email}</p>
        </a>
</li>
```

Table example:

```
 <table class="table" if.bind="contacts" id="myTable">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>IDs</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr repeat.for="contact of contacts" class="clickable-row ${contact.id === $parent.selectedId ? 'active' : ''}">
      <a route-href="route: contacts; params.bind: {id:contact.id}" click.delegate="$parent.select(contact)">
      <td>${contact.id}</td>
        <td>${contact.name}</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

I know how to get the row onlick to work using jquery without Aurelia as in

```
 $(".class='clickable-row").click(function() {
        window.location = $(this).data("href");
    });
```

but I do not know how to use aurelia navigation with the row click.

The solution does not necessarily need to use jquery onlcick just whatever is appropriate for the Master/Detail scenario with Aurelia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to capture click on `<tr>` specifically

```
<tr repeat.for="contact of contacts" click.delegate="onSelectContact($event, contact)">
    <td style="cursor: pointer;">lalala</td>
</tr>
```

and in your view-model, something like..

```
import { autoinject } from 'aurelia-framework'
import { Router } from 'aurelia-router'
import { Contact } from '../la/la'

@autoinject
export class Contacts {
    contacts: Array<Contact> = []

    constructor(private router: Router) {
    }

    onSelectContact (event: UIEvent, contact: Contact) {
        ...... // do whatever
        this.router.navigateToRoute('contact', {id: contact.id})
    }

    ...
}
```

however, this requires your router config to contain a

```
{ route: 'contact/:id', name: 'contact', moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('path to module'), title: 'Contact' }
```